# How to change the dag bag folder for Airflow web ui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Airflow scheduler is picking up the dags from the correct folder as per set in the airflow.cfg file. However, Airflow ui webserver is picking the dags from wrong folder.
I realised this via looking at the stdout of the terminal in which airflow webserver is running: `[2018-10-08 14:26:48,519] [15535] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/aviral/airflow/dags`

Note, my airflow.cfg file has:

```
# The folder where your airflow pipelines live, most likely a
# subfolder in a code repository
# This path must be absolute
dags_folder = /home/aviral/dev/airflow_learning/airflow_home/dags
```

Comment: Are you sure the webserver is using the same config file?

Comment: It was my folly, forgot to put the same environment variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks to me like you have multiple Airflow installations. I think you have to check the UI in the Admin -> Configuration menu.

That will tell you which Airflow is active and set as `AIRFLOW_HOME` and `AIRFLOW_CONFIG`.

If the `AIRFLOW_CONFIG` environment variable is not set, it will always default to your home directory. You'll have to set it to something like this: 
`AIRFLOW_CONFIG=$AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg`.

Answer (score 4):

Change the Dag folder by using the following commands.

Open the .bashrc or .zshrc user file of the terminal

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Add the below commands in the file

```
 export AIRFLOW_HOME='/var/www/html/airflow'
 export AIRFLOW_CONFIG=$AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg
```

Run the .bashrc file by using the below command.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now if you run airflow webserver, it will pick the dags from the AIRFLOW_HOME/dags directory.